# Monte Carlo integration - convergence

Tags: computational-physics, integration

I have a 5D integral being calculated with a Monte Carlo uniform random sampling. The issue is that the region of integration is very small and for 100000 points I get only around 20-30 points every time. The function has to be calculated several times for a certain parameter, which doesn't change the integration region, but changes only the magnitude of the result (which is good, I suppose).

After several runs I gathered some hundreds of points which are a valid match for the integration region. I was thinking about use those points to improve the integration result, but how can I do that, in a correct way?

Comment: Are you actually drawing from $\mathcal U(0,\,1)$ and checking if the point is in the region? Or do you find $\mathcal U(a,\,b)$?

Comment: what's U(0,1) ? Let's say for example I'm drawing points from $x \in [0,10]$ and $y \in [0,5]$ and the condition is $x^2 + y^2 < 1$. I'm keeping all the points that respect this condition, because they are so few.

Comment: $\mathcal U(0,\,1)$ is standard terminology for "uniform random number between 0 & 1." your constraint for $x,\,y$ makes it impossible 90% of the time simply because of the radicand can't be negative ($y=\sqrt{1-x}$ only works if $x\leq1$)

Comment: @KyleKanos of course, that was only a representative example, the conditions here are more complicated. I'm trying to show that the points are difficult to find, that's the essence of the question.

Comment: So if that's what is going on, you need to find a way to adjust the parameters. Without being more explicit in the parameters, ranges & equations, it is unlikely anyone can help beyond my first sentence in this comment.

Comment: I expected non-trivial answers, but thanks :)

Comment: Nontrivial answers *can* come if you are more descriptive in your request.

Comment: this is not a request for integration optimization, I was asking what to do when the hit rate is very low.

Comment: Well you either accept a low hit rate or you optimize the constraints to increase hit rate. I guess another alternative is to draw from non-uniform distributions, but you'd have to account for that in the integral

Comment: my approach was going to be drawing from the pool of already discovered points and mix them with non-fitting points, and I was wondering how to do that properly.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Markov Chain Monte Carlo (usually just abbreviated to MCMC), but that's not something I'm familiar with in practice.